# asynchronous callback doesn't work on a save event crm 2011 and silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm using silverlight o-data services to interact with CRM 2011 and I'm getting some problems when I try to save my data on clicking on the save button of my CRM forms.

When I click on the save button, I call my Silverlight function (`OnSave`) that will save my data, and as you know On Silverlight OData Services saving is asynchronous.  I have to create two functions, the first one will beginSave and the second one will endSave.

Is there a way to complete saving data on the same function?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use anonymous methods so that there is only one *named* function.  It will often save you some typing and make the code a bit shorter and easier to read, but there's still technically more than one function.

If you're using C# 5.0 you can use the new async/await features such that you will write only one function, and you won't *explicitly* create any other functions, even though behind the scenes one or more additional functions will end up being created.  This is some very fun stuff that *dramatically* eases programming in paradigms such as Silverlight where everything is asynchronous.

You could technically (possibly, depending on the needed signatures) make a single function that was both the begin and end method, and tried to determine which it needed to do inside of the method.  This would be terribly, terribly ugly and hard to work with, but would technically only require one method.  Please don't do this.